# Display checkbox output on different page

Tags: php, checkbox, get

How do I display my output on different php page i have here my code and upon checking the boxes and clicking the submit button i want the output to be displayed on the other page but current my code here is displaying only the output on the same page , your help is much appreciated thanks

```
<?php
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM icheck ";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
 //$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
//MY FIRST PAGE
<form method="POST">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Check</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        $i=1;

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
echo'<tr>
    <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['price'].'</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value='.$row['id'].'></td>

    ';
    $i++;
    }
    }
        ?>

</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
</form>

//OUTPUT TO BE DISPLAYED ON OTHER PAGE or 2nd PAGE
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(!empty($_POST['check'])) {
// Counting number of checked checkboxes.
$checked_count = count($_POST['check']);
echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";
if(isset($_POST['check'])){
$sum=0;
foreach($_POST['check'] as $selected) {
    $ah="SELECT * FROM icheckWHERE id=".$selected;
    $rowz = mysqli_query($connect, $ah);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($rowz);
    echo $row['name']."</br>";
    $test=$row['price'];
    $sum+=(int)$test;

}

echo "Jay Total na ket: ".$sum;
}
}
else{
echo "<b>Please Select Atleast One Option.</b>";
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form in first page not contain form action so you have to put form action to second page then posted data can be catch from second page.

//MY FIRST PAGE

```
<form method="POST" action="mysecondpage.php">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Check</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        $i=1;

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
echo'<tr>
    <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['price'].'</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value='.$row['id'].'></td>

    ';
    $i++;
    }
    }
        ?>

</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: hmm i see imma deal with it

Answer (score 0):

At first vardump this `$_POST['check']`. Is it array your code will work. By vardump the variable, You find your solve.

You can share with me your vardump result.